# Genexus test run error

Tags: c#, genexus

I am new to `Genexus`, and I have been following [this tutorial](http://get.genexus.com/quickstart/Genexus_Trial_Tutorial_EN.pdf) but unfortunately as soon as I ran it it gives me this error:

[image]

I tried reviewing the steps many times and googling it, unlucky I cannot found answers.

Comment: Rick, could you try again? Maybe the server was down on that moment. Are you using GeneXus X Evolution 2?

Comment: I have tried it many times yesterday, and tried it again today but still it gives me the same error. Btw, I am using Genexus X Evolution 2 Trial version 10.2.75733 U4

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have misconfigured the server address where you want to deploy and run the web application.

Anyway you could copy the generated content (under the web directory of your model) to a created IIS application and run it manually in a browser.

I hope it helps.